# Is it possible to add a VM to an existing VLAN on a physical network?

Tags: virtual-machine, firewall, vmware-workstation, vlan

I have a **Cisco ASA 5505** running firewalls and other network functionalities including a VLAN and I have VMware workstation running multiple VM that have Active Directory, DNS, and other services.

I will like to move one or 2 of these VMs from a VMware Workstation Network to a Cisco VLAN Network on my ASA 5505.

Has anyone attempted to do this and succeeded ?

Answer (score 0):

VMWARE workstation has limited support for multiple VLANs. If you have two NICs on your system, then you can set one Network Adapter in Bridge Mode, and other in NAT, this will allow you to use two separate Networks. On the Cisco ASA, depending on your license, you can setup one VLAN as inside, and other as DMZ and third is outside. But if you have the License, you can have multiple Inside VLANs, and use two of them on two seperate NICs on your System.